# First Scanner is not working, when i am using WHILE loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

In this code, when the loop starts for the first time it doesn't stop at the first scanner input, but just goes to the second one.  However, when the loop starts for the second time it works fine.  Why does this happen?

```
Scanner jass=new Scanner(System.in);
while(userChoose != 1){
    //1.Add a course
    System.out.println("\nProvide a course code:");
    String courseCodeInput=jass.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> onlyCCArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    onlyCCArray.add(courseCodeInput);

    System.out.println("\nProvide a course name:"); 
    String courseNameInput=jass.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> codeNArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    codeNArray.add(courseNameInput);

    System.out.println("Would you like to [A]dd a new course or [R]eturn to the previous menu? ");
    String userChoice=jass.nextLine();

    for(int q=0;q<99;q++){
        if(userChoice.equals("a")||userChoice.equals("A")){
            userChoose=0;
            break;
        }else if(userChoice.equals("r")||userChoice.equals("R")){
            userChoose=1;
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Input:");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you gotta use **do while**

Comment: i tried using do while....it still doesn't work

Comment: The problem may be in “\n” from the previous user input that wasn’t consumed. Does the user enter anything before that?

Comment: i have also tried that, it still doesn't work.